# Why does iPhone give an authentication error when installing .ipa using iTunes?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipa

I have exported an archive as an ad-hoc distribution, but when installing it to an unlocked phone, right at the end, it says there's an authentication error.

How do I fix this?

My friend sent me a video from iTools, the upload progress reaches the end but the message is, "Authentication Failure".

iTunes doesn't give an error. The app icon appears but after the radial loader animation, it disappears.

Comment: Can you include the error that you're seeing in your question?

Comment: My friend sent me a video from iTools, the upload progress reaches the end but the message is, "Authentication Failure". iTunes doesn't give an error. The app icon appears but after the radial loader animation, it disappears.

Comment: Make sure that .ipa has the UDID added in provisioning of the device on which you're installing it.

Comment: Where does one add that?

Comment: ...in the developer website!